# Any possible way to extract traffic data from Waze Live map?

Tags: google-maps, web-scraping, flutter, dart, waze

I am creating an app using Flutter/Dart the relies on Traffic data. The best source of Traffic data that i have found is through Waze. Therefore, i was wondering if there was any way to scrape/extract traffic data from waze?
If there is how would i go about doing it?

Thank you in advance!

Mainly interested in Accidents, road closures, congestion information, hazards on the road

Comment: I don't think waze allows developers to access such data.

Comment: yeah, i dont believe it does either, but i was wondering if there was a way to scrape the data they have on their live map @ https://www.waze.com/livemap

Comment: Maybe [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77122888) answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into their SDKs/APIs https://developers.google.com/waze/